# MVC - should a model interact with (an)other model(s)? Or the controller should do that?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

Apologise if it sounds a dumb question, but if I never ask, I'll never learn. I have been recently working with the MVC implementing pattern, and I'm still learning stuff, so please be patient with me.

I've been recently working on a multi-languages website that uses a custom MVC framework for a client. In some places I'd need to display some information from more than one table, like an article (from the articles table), the name of the languages that this article is written in (from the languages table), the languages that this article is not yet written in (from the languages table also), and the author (from the authors table).

I have a model for the articles, a model for the languages, and a model for the authors, and each has its own controller.

If I only query articles tables only or the authors tables only, there is no issue, but the confusion comes when I want to display information from this different tables into a single view.

How I should do that?

1. Instantiate a `language model object` and an `author model object` in the **`article controller`** and call their related functions to get the data and then combine/merge their data with the data from the `article model` (all in the **`article controller`** as mentioned)?
2. Instantiate the `language model` and the `author model` in the **`article model`** and call their functions to get their data, then combine/merge the their data with the data from the **`article model`** itself?
3. Do a **join** or **nested select** in the **`article model`** to get the data from multiple tables, and not interact with any other model, even if that mean some queries will be repeated in more than on model?
4. Another approach?

What is the best way do that?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in several ways:
- Create a view (a virtual table of MySQL) which using join, nested select or whatever you want to achieve all necessary information and create a model on top of this view in MVC (this model can only retrieve info from the view not alter it, however)
- Use repository pattern. A repository wrap many models and you can implement business logic (which might be CRUD on multiple models/tables) here. The controller simply use the repository instead of model.
In summary the model, repository should wrapping all the business logic of its own never let the controller do these stuff.
Regards,

Comment: Isn't creating a view, and  creating a model on top of it will cause that articles will have two models (one for reading data and one for modifying it) and two controllers (one for each model)? I'll look into repository pattern, but  don't think the project is large enough for implementing a repository pattern for it.